# No Bluetooth adapters found after installing 14.04 over Zorin OS

Tags: bluetooth

I was using Zorin os 5 on my Compaq Presario 510 and at that time my in-built Bluetooth was working perfectly, but after I installed Ubuntu 14.04 it says

> no Bluetooth adapters found.

I was able to reproduce this by reinstalling Zorin 5 (Bluetooth working again), and then reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 (no Bluetooth adapters found).

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a10] (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a12] (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a13] (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2841] (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2847] (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:2849] (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2815] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2828] (rev 03)
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
30:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4357] (rev 10)
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b159 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05c6:6001 Qualcomm, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$ grep -i bluetooth /var/log/syslog
Feb 2 10:48:07 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Feb 2 10:48:07 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Starting SDP server
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.662876] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.662920] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.662933] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.662937] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.662958] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init time plugin
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init alert plugin
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.886487] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.886502] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 24.886513] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 25.200795] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 25.200800] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Feb 2 10:48:08 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 25.200812] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Feb 2 10:48:09 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Feb 2 10:48:09 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[769]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.872469] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.872502] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.872513] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.872516] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.872532] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.877663] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.877676] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 27.877684] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Starting SDP server
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init time plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init alert plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 28.292665] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 28.292670] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 kernel: [ 28.292682] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Feb 3 10:05:19 jaladhi-Compaq-510 bluetoothd[899]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally have Bluetooth turned on and it's able to find my Android device and pair with it.

I booted the Zorin 5 installer disc and selected to run live without installation. The Bluetooth icon at the bottom panel was showing that Bluetooth  was switched off so I turned it on and it was working, I could find Bluetooth  devices.

I exited the live Zorin 5 by shutting it down with Bluetooth turned on, removed the installer disc and turned my laptop on again. Bluetooth on my Ubuntu 15.04 started working. I could pair with it and share files.

I cannot use my Android device to network through Bluetooth which I was able to do in Zorin, and I can't transfer large files (over 5 MB) but I'm happy.